# Create a view to display nested data

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

My Model
    config:{
        fields: [
           { name: 'AcctManagFirst', type: 'string' },
           { name: 'AcctManagLast', type: 'string' },
           { name: 'Name', type: 'string' },
           { name: 'Terms', type: 'string' },
           { name: 'Freight', type: 'string' },
           { name: 'Taxable', type: 'string' },
           { name: 'Taxtable', type: 'string' },
           { name: 'TaxTableRate', type: 'string' },
           { name: 'BillToAddr', type: 'string' },
           { name: 'BCity', type: 'string' },
           { name: 'BState', type: 'string'},
           { name: 'BZip', type: 'string' },
           { name: 'WHAddr', type: 'string' },
           { name: 'WHCity', type: 'string' },
           { name: 'WHState', type: 'string' },
           { name: 'WHZip', type: 'string' },

and my store

```
config:{
    model: 'Sample.model.User',


    proxy:
        {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://xxx.xxx.com/customer_info.php',
         buildUrl : function (request) {
         var url = this.getUrl(request),
         params = request.getParams() || {};

         url = url + params.CustNo;
         request.setUrl(url);
          return this.callParent([request]);
          },

       reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'content'
            }
        }

  I will get the user data from the store... how to write a view that display data with respect to the user.. user data changes .. now I can write the static data but I need the data to be dynamic..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your question is awfully vague and difficult to answer. 
I think what you're trying to accomplish is to have a list populated dynamically from your store which when tapped will display a detail view.

You'll need to put together a [list view](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List) to display your data as well as a [container](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Container) for the detail view.

You will also need a [controller](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller) with a reference to both views and a control on the list view's itemtap event. The method called from that control should set the data into your detail view then push that view onto the Viewport.

I can be more specific but as I mentioned this question is too vague to put together any kind of example for you. Adding a hardcoded set of data to your store would help, as well as full class examples of your views, stores, controllers and models.

Comment: I am sorry it really looks confusing because of mixing code and text ..here I am adding the url senchafiddle that has my model,store and view I want to display ..http://www.senchafiddle.com/#F6kim if you go through this url u can see model,store and view I want to display but the view is not working. Thank you

Comment: I got your [fiddle](http://new.senchafiddle.com/#WTjHU/) working (you do need the app.js) but I am still not sure what it is you are wanting to do.

Comment: I want to display the data in my view from the store ... if you see my view you can understand .how to retrieve data from the store to put it in view. please check my view in the fiddle so that you can know how I want to display my data .

Comment: You fiddle isn't there...I have only used that site a little but it seems to be flaky about keeping your stuff around, or I don't know how to use it. :) Either way...I think this is what you're looking for - [Ext.form.Panel - setRecord](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-setRecord). Good Luck!

Comment: It worked ... Used getStore and setRecord methods. Thank you :)